# each() toggle checkboxes append this value else if statement in jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, append, each

```
var CheckFUN = function() {
    var numberCheckedVAR = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
    $('#checkMonitorNUMBER').text(numberCheckedVAR);

    var $checkMonitor = $('#checkMonitor').empty();
    $('.GruppoCheck :checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        if(numberCheckedVAR <= 1){
            $checkMonitor.append('<span>#' + $(this).val() + '#</span>');
        }
        else if(numberCheckedVAR >= 2){
            $checkMonitor.append('<span>@' + $(this).val() + '@</span>');
        }
    });
}

$('.GruppoCheck input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    CheckFUN();
});
```

If I toggle in the sequence, now it works not properly:

```
@aaaaaaa@@bbbbbbb@@ccccccc@
```

I need that only the first time when I toggle a checkbox, only the first element has `#` and the result that i want is this:

```
#aaaaaaa#@bbbbbbb@@ccccccc@
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z46fs/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2vMhq/ hope this is what you want

Comment: @Satpal Absolutely Perfect! Post answer and i will accetpt it! :) Many thanks!

Comment: @user3746998, another way http://jsfiddle.net/73hXT/. Give accpeted answer to best answer which helped you the most

Answer (score 1):

```
var CheckFUN = function() {
    var numberCheckedVAR = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
    $('#checkMonitorNUMBER').text(numberCheckedVAR);

    var $checkMonitor = $('#checkMonitor').empty();
    $('.GruppoCheck :checkbox:checked').each(function(index) {
        if(index == 0){
            $checkMonitor.append('<span>#' + $(this).val() + '#</span>');
        }
        else{
            $checkMonitor.append('<span>@' + $(this).val() + '@</span>');
        }
    });
}


$('.GruppoCheck input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    CheckFUN();
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/cqvt8/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var CheckFUN = function () {
    //cache the checked items reference for future use
    var $checked = $('input:checkbox:checked');
    $('#checkMonitorNUMBER').text($checked.length);

    //set the content using .html() - no need to call .empty() as a separate call
    $('#checkMonitor').html(function () {
        //use .map() convert the checked element collection to a html representation
        return $checked.map(function (idx, el) {
            var seperator = idx == 0 ? '#' : '@';
            return '<span>' + seperator + this.value + seperator + '</span>'
        }).get().join('')
    })
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nhyDp/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `index` to know the first element in `.each()` loop, like this :

```
$('.GruppoCheck :checkbox:checked').each(function(index) {
        if(index== 0){
            $checkMonitor.append('<span>#' + $(this).val() + '#</span>');
        }
        else {
            $checkMonitor.append('<span>@' + $(this).val() + '@</span>');
        }
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z46fs/3/)**